Chrome extension Dev issue
I’m a developer, just finish developing a chrome extension but I’m having an issue where my content script runs on all frames at once ,
Let me give some more light, my extension takes a screenshot of the current screen of the user. But the thing is that some website could have iframes and things of the sort .when ever I get to site like that and I try to perform the screenshot, since the logic is on my content.js, I have multiple occurrences and it becomes all bugged out , how can I fix this?, I want to be able to capture all frames at once without issue .
Is there a way I can handle this?,
(Ps, the top frame is not always the frame that is intended by the user to work on)
I’ve tried making all_frames : true on the manifest and I’ve also try using self!= top but that just makes the process work on only the top frame and I won’t be able to select areas on other frames

Show the code and demonstrate the problem as well as the desired outcome. The "bugged out" and "without issue" in your description is too vague. So far I can only guess you want to make individual screenshots per each iframe.
